# Preserving metadata after processing shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, metadata

This is really my first time working with metadata and I just have a few concerns in regards to it.

Hypothetically, if I were to merge two shapefiles together and then, explode them back to individual shape, what would the status of the metadata (xml file) look like ? WIll the metadata get altered? Or will it stay the same?

My other question is what would be the best way if I like to preserve the metadata in their original even if the shape has gone through some geoprocessing?

Answer (score 1):

The merge tool does keep the metadata, but oddly enough only the metadata for the first input in the list of merge inputs. As mattytunks21 said, copying the XML file that is associated with the other layer files will save the metadata and then you can just copy and paste the xml contents from one into the other to have all your metadata.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the data you could export the xml files before you do the geoprocessing.